# Capturing value in DG cell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I have a DataGridView bound to a DataTable. How can I detect when a user enters a value into a cell, then populate a value into another cell?

```
    If dataGridView3.CurrentRow.IsNewRow = True then
        If Len(dataGridView3.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3)) = 7 Then
            dataGridView3.SelectedRows(0).Cells(4).Value = "Surprise"
        End If
    End If
```

This code does not throw any errors but when the length is equal to 7, nothing happens in cell 4 (technically cell 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cells(3)` is a [**`DataGridViewCell`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell(v=vs.110).aspx), but `Cells(3).Value` is a `String` (I presume). You're checking the length of the wrong object.

```
If Len(dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value) = 7 Then
```

Also, `Len()` is an old function from the VB6 era. I highly recommed switching to the [**`String.Length` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
Dim CellValue As Object = dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value

If CellValue IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
    CellValue.GetType() Is GetType(String) AndAlso _
     DirectCast(CellValue, String).Length = 7 Then
```

A bit more messy solution perhaps, but the additional checks ensure that no exceptions are thrown by the `If` statement.

Comment: I feel dumb. Thank you. Also, I had to switch to If Len(dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value) = 7 Then

Comment: @user3753620 : Glad I could help! Please remember to mark this as accepted when time allows. Also, see my edit for a proper .NET solution.